# Android Spinner get ID with data from mysql

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, android-spinner

I have a Tab layout with fragment class which has a listview in it and a spinner. All the data inside the listview is populated from my database. **How do I change the data inside my listview by selecting an item in my spinner that gets by ID?**

Here is a sample of my JSON file

```
{
    "game_response": [{
        "EID": "1",
        "teamone": "RRR",
        "teamtwo": "TTT",
        "teamonepts": "69",
        "teamtwopts": "61",
        "e_name": "Basketball",
        "e_gender": "Male"
    }, {
        "EID": "2",
        "teamone": "AAA",
        "teamtwo": "BBB",
        "teamonepts": "61",
        "teamtwopts": "52",
        "e_name": "Basketball",
        "e_gender": "Female"
    }, {
        "EID": "3",
        "teamone": "CCC",
        "teamtwo": "DDD",
        "teamonepts": "56",
        "teamtwopts": "38",
        "e_name": "Football",
        "e_gender": "Male"
    }]
}
```

The **EID is the unique id** for each data in my spinner. How do I get to only show all data from EID 2 on my listview when I select "Basketball Female" from my spinner?

Here is my android code

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.games, container, false);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sp1);
        getJSON();


        getSpinner();
        spinner_fn();

        return rootView;


    }

    private void getSpinner() {
        list1.clear();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(Config.URL_SPIN);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json;


            e_name = new String[JA.length()];
            e_gender = new String[JA.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++) {
                json = JA.getJSONObject(i);
                e_gender[i] = json.getString("e_gender");
                e_name[i] = json.getString("e_name");
            }
            list1.add("All");
            list1.add("NonSports");
            for (int i = 0; i < e_name.length; i++) {
                list1.add(e_name[i] + " " + e_gender[i]);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    private void showJSON1() {
        JSONObject jsonObject;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list9 = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY2);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String EID = jo.getString(Config.TAG_EID);
                String teamone = jo.getString(Config.TAG_teamone);
                String teamonepts = jo.getString(Config.TAG_teamonepts);
                String teamtwo = jo.getString(Config.TAG_teamtwo);
                String teamtwopts = jo.getString(Config.TAG_teamtwopts);
                String e_name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_e_name);
                String e_gender = jo.getString(Config.TAG_e_gender);
                String m_no = jo.getString(Config.TAG_m_no);
                HashMap<String, String> match = new HashMap<>();
                match.put(Config.TAG_EID, EID);
                match.put(Config.TAG_teamone, teamone);
                match.put(Config.TAG_teamonepts, teamonepts);
                match.put(Config.TAG_teamtwo, teamtwo);
                match.put(Config.TAG_teamtwopts, teamtwopts);
                match.put(Config.TAG_e_name, e_name);
                match.put(Config.TAG_e_gender, e_gender);
                match.put(Config.TAG_m_no, m_no);
                list9.add(match);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(), list, R.layout.gamesadapterlayout,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_EID, Config.TAG_teamone, Config.TAG_teamonepts, Config.TAG_teamtwo, Config.TAG_teamtwopts, Config.TAG_e_name, Config.TAG_e_gender, Config.TAG_m_no},
                new int[]{R.id.team1, R.id.score1, R.id.team2, R.id.score2, R.id.Type, R.id.s_gender});
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



    private void GETJSON1() {
        class gETJSON1 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showJSON1();
            }


            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_VOLLEYBALL);
                return s;
            }
        }
        gETJSON1 gj = new gETJSON1();
        gj.execute();
    }



    private void spinner_fn() {
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list1);
        spinner1.setAdapter(spinner);
        spinner1.setSelection(0);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {


                    case 0:
                        GETJSON1();
                        List<? extends Map<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), list, R.layout.gamesadapterlayout,
                                new String[]{Config.TAG_EID, Config.TAG_teamone, Config.TAG_teamonepts, Config.TAG_teamtwo, Config.TAG_teamtwopts, Config.TAG_e_name, Config.TAG_e_gender, Config.TAG_m_no},
                                new int[]{R.id.team1, R.id.score1, R.id.team2, R.id.score2, R.id.Type, R.id.s_gender});
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                 break;
                    case 1:
                       GETJSON1();
                        List<? extends Map<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), list, R.layout.gamesadapterlayout,
                                new String[]{Config.TAG_EID, Config.TAG_teamone, Config.TAG_teamonepts, Config.TAG_teamtwo, Config.TAG_teamtwopts, Config.TAG_e_name, Config.TAG_e_gender, Config.TAG_m_no},
                                new int[]{R.id.team1, R.id.score1, R.id.team2, R.id.score2, R.id.Type, R.id.s_gender});
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        break;
                    case 2:

                        GETJSON1();
                        List<? extends Map<String, ?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), list, R.layout.gamesadapterlayout,
                                new String[]{Config.TAG_EID, Config.TAG_teamone, Config.TAG_teamonepts, Config.TAG_teamtwo, Config.TAG_teamtwopts, Config.TAG_e_name, Config.TAG_e_gender, Config.TAG_m_no},
                                new int[]{R.id.team1, R.id.score1, R.id.team2, R.id.score2, R.id.Type, R.id.s_gender});
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        break;
```

Comment: U know how many items will be in your spinner??

Comment: yes, example if I have 5

Comment: If you know that, then you can get all items from your server first, then add them in some database, after that you can easily take care of changing the spinners item.

Comment: What I am asking is how do I change the items in my listview when I clicked an item in my spinner?

Comment: Oh....ok....let me change a few things then I'll answer to your question shortly after that.

Comment: @Mohammad ok sir thanks

Comment: First of all, It would be better if you use some library for your connection stuff...like [retrofit][1]....after that, you easily can save stuff in your database with some sort of ORM like [Sugar][2]....the rest is so much ez


  [1]: http://square.github.io/retrofit/
  [2]: http://satyan.github.io/sugar/

Let me know if u had any questions